# Parametric visibility and order of tkinter labels

Tags: python, tkinter, polymorphism

I'm writing software which allows a user to view data in a number of different formats, and they can switch between formats at any time. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this than switching between subclasses, and if not, if there's a better way to write this than I have.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Display(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, relief='sunken', padding='20')

        self.widgets = [
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #1"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #2"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #3"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #4"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #5"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #6"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #7"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #8"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #9"),
            ttk.Label(self, text="Data Value #10"),
        ]

    def show(self):
        for i in self.widgets:
            i.pack()


class Display1(Display):
    def show(self):
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                widget.pack()


class Display2(Display):
    def show(self):
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                widget.pack()


class Display3(Display):
    def show(self):
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            if i > 4:
                widget.pack()


class Display4(Display):
    def show(self):
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            if i < 5:
                widget.pack()


class Display5(Display):
    def show(self):
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            self.widgets[-i].pack()


class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        #
        #
        # Initialize buttons to select how to view the data.
        self.selection = tk.StringVar(self, value="Option 1")
        self.display_options = [
            ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="Option 1", variable=self.selection, value="Option 1", command=self.change_display),
            ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="Option 2", variable=self.selection, value="Option 2", command=self.change_display),
            ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="Option 3", variable=self.selection, value="Option 3", command=self.change_display),
            ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="Option 4", variable=self.selection, value="Option 4", command=self.change_display),
            ttk.Radiobutton(self, text="Option 5", variable=self.selection, value="Option 5", command=self.change_display),
        ]

        for i, button in enumerate(self.display_options):
            button.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=20)

        #
        #
        # Initialize the frame holding the data
        self.data_frame = Display(self)
        self.data_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=10)
        self.data_frame.show()

    def change_display(self):
        for i in self.data_frame.pack_slaves():
            i.pack_forget()
        self.data_frame.grid_forget()

        match self.selection.get():
            case "Option 1":
                self.data_frame = Display1(self)
            case "Option 2":
                self.data_frame = Display2(self)
            case "Option 3":
                self.data_frame = Display3(self)
            case "Option 4":
                self.data_frame = Display4(self)
            case "Option 5":
                self.data_frame = Display5(self)
            case _:
                self.data_frame = Display(self)

        self.data_frame.show()
        self.data_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window()
    win.mainloop()
```

The program initializes a window with a selection of formats to view the data, and shows the data in some default format. Each subclass of `Display` only overrides the `show()` method.

This isn't the entire program I'm working on, but the important part is that the subclasses of `Display` don't actually initialize themselves, and only override certain parent methods. Is there a better way to change the way the data is displayed than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Display` and `Window` should both follow *has-a* rather than *is-a* for better loose coupling; that is, they should keep the widgets to themselves and only selectively expose functionality as needed.

Subclassing is not justified in this case.

Your conditional packing loops (1) should not use conditions at all, and (2) should simply iterate over a `range` of indices instead.

You had the right(ish) idea to use a `Var`, but it shouldn't be a `StringVar` - it should be an `IntVar`, since that's usable as an index.

You need to make use of loops to fill your label and radio lists.

Rather than manually checking every single option, just pull the value of the `IntVar` and use that as an index into a tuple of ranges.

Rather than `command`, prefer to trace the variable itself.

After these changes you will not need to save your `display_options` and the parent `Tk` as members of your class.

### Suggested

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from typing import Sequence

displays = (
    range(1, 10, 2),
    range(2, 11, 2),
    range(6, 11, 1),
    range(1,  6, 1),
    range(10, 0, -1),
)


class Display:
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk) -> None:
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(parent, relief='sunken', padding='20')
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=10)

        self.labels = [
            ttk.Label(self.frame, text=f'Data Value #{i}')
            for i in range(1, 11)
        ]

    def show(self, indices: Sequence[int]) -> None:
        for label in self.frame.pack_slaves():
            label.pack_forget()

        for i in indices:
            self.labels[i - 1].pack()


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        parent = tk.Tk()
        self.mainloop = parent.mainloop

        self.selection = tk.IntVar(parent)
        self.selection.trace_add('write', self.change_display)

        for i in range(5):
            button = ttk.Radiobutton(
                parent, text=f"Option {i + 1}",
                variable=self.selection, value=i,
            )
            button.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=20)

        self.data_frame = Display(parent)
        self.selection.set(0)

    def change_display(self, name: str, index: str, mode: str) -> None:
        display = displays[self.selection.get()]
        self.data_frame.show(display)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window()
    win.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot]

An alternative method involves calls to `grid`/`gridremove` instead of `pack`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from typing import Sequence

DISPLAYS = (
    range( 1, 10,  2),
    range( 2, 11,  2),
    range( 6, 11,  1),
    range( 1,  6,  1),
    range(10,  0, -1),
)


class Display:
    def __init__(self, parent: tk.Tk) -> None:
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(parent, relief='sunken', padding='20')
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5)

        self.labels = [
            ttk.Label(self.frame, text=f'Data Value #{i}')
            for i in range(1, 11)
        ]

    def show(self, indices: Sequence[int]) -> None:
        for y, i in enumerate(indices):
            self.labels[i - 1].grid(row=y, column=0)
        for i in set(range(1, 11)) - set(indices):
            self.labels[i - 1].grid_remove()


class Window:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        parent = tk.Tk()
        self.mainloop = parent.mainloop

        self.selection = tk.IntVar(parent)
        self.selection.trace_add('write', self.change_display)

        for i in range(5):
            button = ttk.Radiobutton(
                parent, text=f"Option {i + 1}",
                variable=self.selection, value=i,
            )
            button.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=20)

        self.data_frame = Display(parent)
        self.selection.set(0)

    def change_display(self, name: str, index: str, mode: str) -> None:
        display = DISPLAYS[self.selection.get()]
        self.data_frame.show(display)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window().mainloop()
```